# How to segregate computers from each other?

Tags: network

I have 10 Windows machines in the same network. I want to create two separate groups i.e. machines 1 to 5 in group "work1" and machines 6 to 10 in "work2".

work1 and work2 have the same internet connection. What I need is the work1 machines segregated from the work2 machines. I don't have a dedicated firewall but I have a Linksys rv042 router. How can this be done? On the router level or can any application can do that?

Comment: I'm afraid that this is a networking question and not a security question. If, as you say in a comment below, that you also have a switch in the network, then this becomes more complicated. The easiest (but not the most secure way) is to firewall the machines from each other and place them in different subnets. This can be done on each machine.

Comment: This is a network question. BTW, you can do something if your switch/router switch support IEEE 802.1-VLAN  : https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/small-business-routers/rv042-inter-vlan-routing/td-p/2314544

Answer (score 2):

You want to configure separate VLANs on your router.

According to https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/routers/csbr/app_notes/RV0xx_an_vlan_78-21017.pdf, in your routers config this is under "Port 
Management > Port Setup". Give the first five a different setting than the other five.

Comment: But work1 and work2 get connected by switch means internet is connected to router and router is connected to switch and then all 10 machines got connected through switch. so how is possible to port setup?

Comment: @AmarGarwad the fact that you have a switch is a VERY important piece of information.

Comment: You might be able to set up VLANs on the switch.

Comment: I have unmanaged switch.

Comment: Then you need to get a managed one. Well, you don't need one, but if you want to create VLANs on the switch, you will.

Comment: any other options?

Comment: Can it be possible that set work1 network as home and work2 network as public?